# Are Pull Requests automatically merged in GitHub/odoo.sh if commit date is ahead of current date?

Tags: git, github, odoo, odoo.sh

I am using `git` for version management in an **Odoo** development project. The repository of this project is also synced with **odoo.sh** where we hosted our project and we do testing and even manage pull requests and branches through it. Some days ago, I accidentally added few commits and *my computer date* was 3 days a head of current date. Then I created a pull request from my branch to the master branch. Then, I think my pull request was merged automatically. So, that's why I want to know if pull requests are merging automatically when our commits date are a head of real world (current) date or not? Do we have any feature for automatic merging of pull requests in **GitHub** or even in **odoo.sh**?

Answer (score 1):

I dont know how to configure github but i dont believe it is using date for auto merge.
All merging is done in github and with github settings.

But in the odoo.sh is in the Branch SETTINGS under the Behavior upon new commits. There date does not mater, it rebuilds if there are new commits on the branch. Who can merge and commit and other such settings are managed in the github.